# How to map JPA Entity with 2 primary keys in Databse

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my database model I have 2 primary keys. I am using JPA with hibernate.

My database model is like

---

### USR_INFO_TBL

COMPANY_ID   
PERSONAL_ID  
FIRST_NAME 
LAST_NAME 
EMAIL 
USR_INFO_TBL_PK

---

Now my JPA entity is like below

```
 @Entity 
 @Table("USR_INFO_TBL")
 public class UerInfo{
@ID(name ="COMPANY_ID")
private String companyID;

private String personalID;   //what should i write here
@COLUMN(name="firstName") 
private String firstName;

@COLUMN(name="lastName ")
private String lastName;

@COLUMN(name="email")
private String email;

//setters and getters
}
```

How the 2 primary keys can be mapped to a JPA Entity
Can you plz modify the above code.I gone through some posts as i was new to JPA AND HIBERNATE concepts.I was in a confusion

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a class annotated with `@Embeddable` containing the components of the composite key, and in your current, `User` entity you should create a field with this new type.

```
@Entity 
@Table("INFO_USR_TBL")
public class User {
    @EmbeddedId
    private UserId id;

    @Column(name="firstName") 
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    //setters and getters
}

@Embeddable
public class UserId {
    @Column(name="COMPANY_ID")
    String companyId;
    @Column(name="PERSONAL_ID")
    String personalId;
}
```

Comment: @Meskobalazs..how can i know with which name the new pojo class or entity should be and what fields are to be there inside the class by seeing the above database model.no information in that..

Comment: The name itself is irrelevant, the fields are the components of the primary key

Comment: do we need to create a separate class and should contains the 2 primary key fields..am i right?

Comment: But wait! Company ID isn't actually a Foreign Key? That would make more sense.

Comment: thanks..got it. one more thing i want to retrieve a single record from database. Now on which primary key i have to build my query. select c from USER_INFO_TABLE c where fromId<:c.COMPANY_ID and toId>:PERSONAL_ID and later on calling getSingleResult on the query..right?

Comment: Well, as the key is a composite one, you build the query using the composite key. You set both values of the `UserId` object, then pass it as a parameter.

Comment: can u check the query which i mentioned in the comment andcan u do if any modifications required

Comment: `from User where userId = :userId`, remember, this is JPQL (HQL), not SQL

Answer (score 1):

In the JPA specification, it states "A composite primary key must either be represented and mapped as an embeddable class or must be represented as an id class and mapped
to multiple fields or properties of the entity class".

You may change your code to below:

```
public class UserId {
    String companyId;
    String personalId;
}

@Entity 
@Table(name="INFO_USR_TBL")
@IdClass(UserId.class)
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name ="COMPANY_ID")
    private String companyID;
    @Id
    @Column(name ="PERSION_ID")
    private String personalID;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME") 
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;

    //setters and getters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this article [**JPA primary keys**](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id), especially "Composite Primary Key" and "Embedded Primary Key" paragraphs. I think, your case is "Embedded Primary Key" when you need to define class, that will contain all primary key parts you actually need to have.

Comment: I already gone through the above link..I dont understand the concept of 2 entity pojo classes. I have only one pojo class with fields what is the other java entity pojo? can u modify on top of my code so that i get clear idea